# I want to send email to an id at local network

Tags: c#, visual-studio, email

I want to send email to an id at local network using intranet not internet in C#. Please someone help me if possible.

Thanks,
Regards

Comment: id as in what? user? computer? ip?

Comment: actually id is mwaqas@pbp.com.pk whereas pbp.com.pk is local network and mwaqas is id now plz guide me if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely doesn't matter if it is intranet or internet. Somewhere on your intranet there is a mail server that supports SMTP protocol. It maybe program like Unix sendmail, Microsoft Exchange or IBM Lotus Domino. Ask your system administrator to find out address of this mail server. Then use standart .NET API ([example here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/10/432854.aspx), replace smtpserver1 to the address of your mail server and specify username and password if needed) to connect to it and send your mail.

Comment: +1 so long as the user id definitely doubles up as an email address on the corporate mail server. I know it usually does with AD + Exchange; however that said a Recipient Policy can override that - possibly a DirectoryServices lookup for that user's email address might also be required.